# How to customise swagger json(yaml)?

Tags: swagger

I am using swagger with rest api. Can i modify the swagger json(or yaml) ?  I want to customise it like i want to split the #defnitions into #requestdefinition & #responsedefinition. Please guide me.

Comment: perhaps I should start a bounty for this question?